# What is target in gesture recognizer?

Tags: ios

Could any body tells me the usage of the target here?

```
UITapGestureRecognizer(target: , action: )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Target - means the object, where `UIGestureRecognizer` will look to find the action.

From documentation: 
`target` -
an object that is the recipient of action messages sent by the receiver when it recognizes a gesture. nil is not a valid value.

So, for example if you adding `UIGestureRecongnizer` for the view of view controller you have to add `self` as a target.